# Problemas al actualizar objetos en Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

He implementado un método update y delete para los elementos de una Listview. Ambos están funcionando, pero el método update está provocando algo extraño:
Cuando creo un objeto en la base de datos firebase vacía y lo actualizo, ningún problema. Pero cuando creo un segundo objeto e intento actualizar a este segundo objeto, se actualiza el primero que había creado. Creo que el fallo que se está produciendo tiene que ver con la siguiente parte del código, que es la definición del adapter que estoy utilizando. De todas formas el código completo utilizado en la clase AddMedicineModified.java (donde aparece el código de este adaptador) lo he incluido al final de esta pregunta, comentado.

```
 class MedicinaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Medicina> {

    Context context;
    List<Medicina> medicamentos;

    public MedicinaAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,
                           @NonNull List<Medicina> medicamentos) {
        super(context, resource, medicamentos);
        this.context=context;
        this.medicamentos=medicamentos;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return medicamentos.size();
    }

    public Medicina getItem(int pos) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getMedicinaId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public void showInputBox(final Medicina oldItem, final int index){//el edit no está creando un objeto medicina y por eso falla
        final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(AddMedicineModified.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Input Box");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_box_medicine_edit);
        TextView txtMessage=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
        txtMessage.setText("Edite el objeto");
        txtMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4169E1"));
        //esto es para que salga un mensaje que indique al usuario qué tiene que hacer

        //esto para que recupere los valores antiguos
        final EditText editTextName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediNameInput);
        final EditText editTextDosis=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediDosisInput);
        editTextName.setText(oldItem.getNombre());
        editTextDosis.setText(oldItem.getDosis());

        //no se puede crear una nueva medicina

        //hay que guardar los datos en la key del objeto recogido

        Button bt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btMediAct);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               oldItem.setNombre(editTextName.getText().toString());
                oldItem.setDosis(editTextDosis.getText().toString());
                //con estos set anteriores se edita en la listview
                //Tengo que hacer para que edita también en la firebase
                medicinaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
                toastMessage("Objeto editado");

                //ahora para editar en firebase

                final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
                db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            //esto funciona pero al actualizar el segundo creado peta esto
                            /*String k=ds.getKey();
                            String newName= oldItem.getNombre().toString();
                            String newDosis=oldItem.getDosis().toString();
                            Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newName,newDosis);
                            db.child(k).setValue(medicine);
                            break;*/
                            Medicina medicamentoEditar=ds.getValue(Medicina.class);

                                String k=ds.getKey();
                                String newName= oldItem.getNombre().toString();
                                String newDosis=oldItem.getDosis().toString();
                                Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newName,newDosis);
                                db.child(k).setValue(medicine);
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        //Para el objeto i-ésimo recupero el elemento de la lista contenedora
        Medicina medicina=medicamentos.get(i);
        //Recupero el "inflador" de layouts
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater().from(context);
        //Inflo el layout item_message que he definido
        view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_medicina,viewGroup,false);

        //Recupero los componentes del item_message
        TextView nombre=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoNombre);
        TextView dosis=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoDosis);

        //Le asigno los valores del mensaje
        nombre.setText(medicina.getNombre());
        dosis.setText(medicina.getDosis());

        //Inicializamos ImageViews
        ImageButton mEditView;
        mEditView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoEditMedicina);
        ImageButton mDeleteView;
        mDeleteView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoDeleteMedicina);

        mEditView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showInputBox(medicamentos.get(i),i);

            }
        });

        mDeleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//funciona bien
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        final Medicina medicinaBorrar=medicamentos.get(i);
        final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Medicina medicamento=snapshot.getValue(Medicina.class);
                    if (medicinaBorrar.getNombre().equals(medicamento.getNombre())){
                        db.child(snapshot.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                        medicamentos.remove(i);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        toastMessage("Objeto eliminado");
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

                /*medicinas.remove(i);
                notifyDataSetChanged();*/ //esto funciona para quitar de listview pero no de firebase
    }
});

        //Devuelvo la vista que he creado
        return view;
    }
```

La base de datos cuenta con la siguiente estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código completo que estoy utilizando:

```
public class AddMedicineModified extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AddNewMedicine";
    //declaro las variables
    private Button mAddToDB;
    private EditText mnombre;
    private EditText mdosis;

    //variables relacionadas con Firebase: para guardar los datos asociados al determinado usuario logueado, etc
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private DatabaseReference puntoDeAcceso;
    private  String userID;

    //Para que se vean los datos de firebase del usuario
    //
    //private List<Medicina> medicinas;

    private MedicinaAdapter medicinaAdapter;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ChildEventListener childEventListener;

    //Declarar las imágenes ImageView de delete y edit

    private ImageButton mEditView;
    private ImageButton mDeleteView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modified_medicine);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMedicines);

        //MedicinaAdapter con layout creado y lista vacía
        List<Medicina> medicinas = new ArrayList<>();
        medicinaAdapter = new MedicinaAdapter(this, R.layout.item_medicina, medicinas);
        mListView.setAdapter(medicinaAdapter);

        mAddToDB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAñadirMedicinaModified);
        mnombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_medicine_modified);
        mdosis=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_dosis_medicine);

        //Firebase
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        myRef=myRef.child("Medicamentos");

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        //puntoDeAcceso=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Medicamentos").child(userID);
        puntoDeAcceso=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");


        //esto para ver si está bien logeado
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    toastMessage("Has iniciado sesión con: " + user.getEmail());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    toastMessage("Has cerrado bien sesión.");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };

        mAddToDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String newMedicine= mnombre.getText().toString();
                String newDosis=mdosis.getText().toString();
                Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newMedicine,newDosis);
                puntoDeAcceso.push().setValue(medicine);

                toastMessage("Añadiendo " + newMedicine + " a la base de datos...");

            }

        });

        childEventListener=new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                //Si he recuperado un objeto lo muestro en el Log
                if(s!=null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                }
                //Creo un objeto mensaje
                Medicina medicina=dataSnapshot.getValue(Medicina.class);
                //y se lo añado al adapter
                medicinaAdapter.add(medicina);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        puntoDeAcceso.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

    }





    class MedicinaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Medicina> {

        Context context;
        List<Medicina> medicamentos;

        public MedicinaAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,
                               @NonNull List<Medicina> medicamentos) {
            super(context, resource, medicamentos);
            this.context=context;
            this.medicamentos=medicamentos;

        }

        public int getCount(){
            return medicamentos.size();
        }

        public Medicina getItem(int pos) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getMedicinaId(int pos) {
            return pos;


        }

        public void showInputBox(final Medicina oldItem, final int index){//el edit no está creando un objeto medicina y por eso falla
            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(AddMedicineModified.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Input Box");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_box_medicine_edit);
            TextView txtMessage=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
            txtMessage.setText("Edite el objeto");
            txtMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4169E1"));
            //esto es para que salga un mensaje que indique al usuario qué tiene que hacer


            //esto para que recupere los valores antiguos
            final EditText editTextName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediNameInput);
            final EditText editTextDosis=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtMediDosisInput);
            editTextName.setText(oldItem.getNombre());
            editTextDosis.setText(oldItem.getDosis());

            //no se puede crear una nueva medicina

            //hay que guardar los datos en la key del objeto recogido

            Button bt=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btMediAct);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   oldItem.setNombre(editTextName.getText().toString());
                    oldItem.setDosis(editTextDosis.getText().toString());
                    //Con esto actualiza en la ListView pero no en la Firebase
                    //Tengo que hacer para que añada en la firebase
                    medicinaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    toastMessage("Objeto editado");

                    //ahora para cambiar en firebase
                    //hacerlo como en el push
                    final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
                    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                //esto funciona pero al actualizar el segundo creado peta esto
                                /*String k=ds.getKey();
                                String newName= oldItem.getNombre().toString();
                                String newDosis=oldItem.getDosis().toString();
                                Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newName,newDosis);
                                db.child(k).setValue(medicine);
                                break;*/
                                Medicina medicamentoEditar=ds.getValue(Medicina.class);

                                    String k=ds.getKey();
                                    String newName= oldItem.getNombre().toString();
                                    String newDosis=oldItem.getDosis().toString();
                                    Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newName,newDosis);
                                    db.child(k).setValue(medicine);
                                    break;

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            //Para el objeto i-ésimo recupero el elemento de la lista contenedora
            Medicina medicina=medicamentos.get(i);
            //Recupero el "inflador" de layouts
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getLayoutInflater().from(context);
            //Inflo el layout item_message que he definido
            view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_medicina,viewGroup,false);

            //Recupero los componentes del item_message
            TextView nombre=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoNombre);
            TextView dosis=view.findViewById(R.id.medicamentoDosis);


            //Le asigno los valores del mensaje
            nombre.setText(medicina.getNombre());
            dosis.setText(medicina.getDosis());

            //Inicializamos ImageViews
            ImageButton mEditView;
            mEditView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoEditMedicina);
            ImageButton mDeleteView;
            mDeleteView=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.iconoDeleteMedicina);

            mEditView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInputBox(medicamentos.get(i),i);

                }
            });

            mDeleteView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//funciona bien
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            final Medicina medicinaBorrar=medicamentos.get(i);
            final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
            db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Medicina medicamento=snapshot.getValue(Medicina.class);
                        if (medicinaBorrar.getNombre().equals(medicamento.getNombre())){
                            db.child(snapshot.getKey().toString()).removeValue();
                            medicamentos.remove(i);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            toastMessage("Objeto eliminado");
                            break;

                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

                    /*medicinas.remove(i);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();*/ //esto funciona para quitar de listview pero no de firebase
        }
    });




            //Devuelvo la vista que he creado
            return view;
        }
    }


    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Cada listview está formada por un item_medicina.xml cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medicamentoNombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/DarkCyan"
        tools:text="nombre"

         />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medicamentoDosis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/DarkCyan"
        tools:text="dosis"

        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/iconoEditMedicina"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round"

        android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/iconoDeleteMedicina"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iconoEditMedicina">

            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Explica cuál es el contexto desde el que intentas actualizar y qué haces para referirte al elemento que quieres actualizar para que podamos entender un poco la lógica que estás implementando, de lo contrario tendremos que intentar adivinar y es más complicado poder ayudarte. Puedes decirnos por ejemplo: *Aquí determino el elemento que hay que actualizar y luego de esta forma lanzo la actualización*. Dinos también si has depurado algo: *Aquí verifico que efectivamente estoy recuperando la referencia correcta del elemento a actualizar*. Hacer eso te ayudará a ti mismo a saber qué ocurre.

Comment: Si se actualiza siempre el primer objeto que creaste, eso quiere decir que siempre se ejecuta la misma sentencia firebase. Si pudieras dar más detslles del child("Medicamentos"), qué contiene

Comment: @Tony_Bielo he añadido una captura del nodo Medicamentos de la Firebase, para que se vea lo que contiene

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por la sugerencia, acabo de comentar y editar el código y he intentado que resulte más claro ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando modificas / editas cualquier registro bajo la referencia Medicamentos, tus `addValueEventListener` se disparan (ya que estos listeners escuchan todo el tiempo por cambios en la base de datos), por lo que vuelve a recorrerse los objetos y a actualizar tu lista.

Para solucionarlo usa `db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent...` el cual va a atachar una sola vez a la referencia y obtener los datos sin quedarse escuchando por cambios.

Al momento de actualizar la lista en Medicamentos, no vas a volver a hacer el trigger de la solicitud de datos.

Para ver la lista cambiada lo podes hacer con el mismo metodo del adaptador `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Muchas gracias, al modificar esto y otra parte del código conseguí que funcionara

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de manipular Firebase. Por desgracia lo hago de una forma distinta a lo que hiciste. Todo parece estar correcto. Voy a sugerirte unos cambios:

```
DatabaseReference db =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID).child("Medicamentos");
db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                        
    for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        DatabaseReference mdb = db.child(ds.getKey().toString());

        //esto funciona pero al actualizar el segundo creado peta esto

        Medicina medicamentoEditar=ds.getValue(Medicina.class);

        String newName= oldItem.getNombre().toString();
        String newDosis=oldItem.getDosis().toString();
        Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newName,newDosis);

        mdb.child(nombre).setValue(newName);
        mdb.child(dosis).setValue(newDosis);
        break;
...
```

Intenta insertar los valores individualmente:

```
     mdb.child(nombre).setValue(newName);
     mdb.child(dosis).setValue(newDosis);
```

Si no te funcionó, pon un comentario pars editar mi respuesta con otra solución.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, se sigue actualizando el primer objeto de la ListView y no este segundo que he creado

Comment: Un error mío! Debes eliminar la línea de código:       ``Medicina medicine=new Medicina(newName,newDosis);`` que tienes bajo los *String*